What Material could replace Hide as a Drumhead?
My alien race is purely herbivorous and never hunt. That means they do not have animal hides to use for drum heads. Most other uses of animal parts I have found other materials for or ways to work around (e.g. wooden flutes instead of bone, cotton cloths instead of leather). I can't think of how they would make drums though.
If there is really nothing, I will settle for a 'its not the same but close enough' answer. I know some percussion instruments, such as xylophones, are made of wood and the cowbell gives a very hollow sound like a drum despite being made of metal like a cymbal. Could a wooden or metal instrument be close enough to a hide drum to fit the same function musically?

What's available in your world? In this world, anything from ceramics through metal to resin-impregnated bamboo-fibre is used. -1 for lack of research.

-1 for lack of research. Humanity was using precussion long before realizing leather was useful. We have modern versions of those types of drums today. Steel drums, wood drums, shells. Per [ask], you're expected to do your due diligence with research before asking here. Thanks.

For reference see: Stone Drums of Qin and Slot Drum - there's no reason that you absolutely need a membrane at all.

What tec level are your aliens? Matter replication would allow for cruelty free leather. Perhaps they use advanced bio-technology to grow living drums. Can they cast summon drum? Open ended brainstorming questions like this are not suitable for this site.

I pray to gourd that you edit this question to fit better with the site's ways ;) Oh, BTW, have you ever tried whacking the top of a wine-bottle or demijohn with a rolled up newspaper?

I seem to recall that rubber is a vegetable product...

As far as I can tell with quick research there are percussion instruments you could use, from ceramic vases to wooden items there are plenty of things that can be struck and make sound. However none will fully replicate how a drum sounds. Metal or plastic would allow for something more dumlike, or maybe even some kind of resin soaked canvas, but if those options arent available your best bet is basically thin wooden barrels with open bottoms or something similar. It will avoid the unique sound ceramics have and have a more dull sound then metal, but I suspect it will also end up with a more quiet result than if you used hide.
Here is a link to a wiki article on percussion instruments that provides a list of links to info on many different types of instruments you could consider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussion_instrument

Frame Drum Challange

Your sophonts are obligate herbivores. They never hunted animals, never domesticated animals, and never used any animal products of any kind.

This means that these people will most likely never develop the kinds of drum that requires a thin, strong, flexible resonating surface --- a drum head. Animal skins are superior in this regard, as they can be treated (tanned), placed over the end of a tube and tightened with ropes to create a membrane that vibrates with something akin to a tone. Generally drums of this sort aren't tunable, but as technology progresses, nakers will turn into timpani which are tunable.

Generally speaking, there are no other substances that will do the trick early enough in your people's cultural history to spur the development of drums. Some leaves get pretty big, but they don't stretch well and often tear too easily. Wood can be planed really thin, but that will require technology far in advance of the people who would invent the drum. Metal, too, would likely come too late.

Likely, your sophonts will focus on those materials they do have access to and will make percussive instruments from those:

Lithophones are literally pieces of tuned stone.


Metallophones are tuned pieces of metal like gongs and bells.


Instruments can also be made from whole logs.


Eventually, someone is going to invent paper, and then they'll have a material that can be fashioned into a drum head that mimics hide fairly well.


Until they get to this point, there really is nothing that has the same qualities as animal hide. Realistically speaking, even if they could make a drum with paper heads, they probably wouldn't simply because this kind of drum was never part of their culture and thus not a part of their musical expression.

I would suggest that their percussive music is not merely rhythmic, but far more tonally complex and harmonic than typical drums can produce.
